# Genitive in "alle des Staates Überdrüssigen"

Tags: grammar, genitive

From Der Spiegel

> 1985 war Wonnerberger von Dresden nach Leipzig versetzt worden -- und schafft nun für **alle des Staates Überdrüssigen** in der Nikolaikirche einen zentralen Anlaufpunkt, ...

What is the construction for "alle des Staates Überdrüssigen"? Why is the genitive used here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective [überdrüssig](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCberdr%C3%BCssig) is used with the genitive or (alternatively and less common) with the accusative to express that someone is weary of or fed up with something. Why the genitive? Well, that's just the way it is...

In the sentence you quote *überdrüssig* is used as a noun: "die Überdrüssigen" = "die überdrüssigen Menschen". So

> alle des Staates Überdrüssigen

means

> all (people) who are weary of the state (or government)

Comment: Would "... alle Überdrussigen des Staates" also work?

Comment: @karoshi Good question. No, it wouldn't. It would sound strange and would probably be read as "all people in the state who are weary of anything".

Answer (score 3):

*überdrüssig* can be used with Genitive or Dative, but it will have different meanings:

> Ich bin *des Freundes* überdrüssig. (I'm fed up with the friend)
>   Ich bin *dem Freunde* überdrüssig. (The friend is fed up with me)

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberdruessig